# Problem with installation and using OpenBLAS and Armadillo at Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, installation, ubuntu-12.04, armadillo, openblas

I need to install OpenBLAS and Armadillo at Ubuntu 12.04. Despite following steps from instructions and readme, I can't do this. In fact it is even hard to describe what I do wrong, or what is the problem exactly.

I am aware that I am asking a lot, however I a quite desperate right now. If somebody would be capable of guiding me, from the very beginning to the end I would be very greatfull. What to do, in which directory etc.

The effect I expect: I can compile programs, which uses Armadillo library.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 is outdated and [no longer supported](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/).

Comment: @hbrerkere I am aware. Unfortunately it doesn't depend on me and I have to deal with it.

Comment: You will continue to have many problems if you try to use something so old. Push back, save yourself the trouble and install Ubuntu 19.04. Then install OpenBLAS and Armadillo directly from Ubuntu repositories. `sudo apt-get install libarmadillo-dev`. Similar command for OpenBLAS

Comment: I would be glad if I could do that. Unfortunately, as I said, It doesn't depend on me.